# Why can I not install oathlib on new python environment?

Tags: python, pip, package

I used pyenv to install python 3.9.0, and then I created a virtual environment with 3.9.0. I have installed all the pip packages I need for my regular running of my python projects, except that one of them won't install:

```
> pip install oathlib
ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement oathlib (from versions: none)
ERROR: No matching distribution found for oathlib
```

The problem is I am running a virtual environment just like this one on another pc, and I installed oathlib on it a few weeks ago, and it runs fine.

How can I get oathlib installed? Is there a problem with some latest version of oathlib that it just won't install in my pyenv? My pip package is the latest one available, so pip is not the issue.

Comment: Are you sure it's oathlib https://pypi.org/project/oathlib/ and not oauthlib https://pypi.org/project/oauthlib/ ?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe u wanna install OAuthlib, I don't find oathlib?
`pip install oauthlib`

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: that was it - minding the capital letters. OAuthlib works, but oauthlib doesn't work. Thanks!